# Laravel Accessing Foreign Key Using Eloquent Where Clause

Tags: php, laravel, collections, eloquent

I have two models called Item and Sale where

```
class Item extends Model
{   
    public function sale()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Sale', 'sale_id');
    }
}
```

and

```
class Sale extends Model
{
    public function item()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Sale', 'item_id');
    }
}
```

This is my migration files for Items

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('items', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('code');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('location');
            $table->double('buy_price');
            $table->double('sell_price');
            $table->integer('quantity');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

And Sales

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('sales', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->date('date');
            $table->integer('quantity');
            $table->double('sell_price');
            $table->double('subtotal');
            $table->integer('item_id')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::table('sales', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreign('item_id')->references('id')->on('items')
                  ->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
        });
    }
```

I recorded the daily sales data to see what are the items sold that day. Therefore I wanted to view the sales daily. And this is what I have done in my controller.

```
class SaleController extends Controller
{
    public function show($date)
    {
        $sales = Sale::where('date', $date)->get();
        return view('sale.detail', compact('sales'));
    }
}
```

And finally in my blade, I did this to call the information of the items

```
@foreach($sales as $sale)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $sale->item->code }}</td>
        <td>{{ $sale->item->name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $sale->sell_price }}</td>
        <td>{{ $sale->quantity }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

In the end I got **Trying to get property of non-object**
Can someone enlighten me what is wrong with my code?
I am relatively new in Laravel but I'm keen on trying different things to see what this framework can do.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you share the sales and items table structure? You might want to check if all the result have the related item data. This shouldn't happen if you're enforcing foreign key constraints. Do share more lines from the error as well.

Comment: I added the migration codes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just noticed that your relationship is defined wrong. Change `App\Sale` to `App\Item` in your `item` relationship. Guess a minor slip up.

```
class Sale extends Model
{
    public function item()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Item', 'item_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: My gosh! You were right! Thanks a lot. I guess I really need to take a few hours break.

Answer (score 1):

Since you need to access the `item` object multiple times, the better way to do it is to eager load it as:

```
public function show($date)
{
    $sales = Sale::with('item')->where('date', $date)->get();
    return view('sale.detail', compact('sales'));
}
```

Then you can leave your blade file as it is.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried as you said and I still get the same error. Now, I'm trying to use raw query instead. Thanks for answering anyway

Comment: At which line are you getting the error? Try printing the data in the variables, so you can see how you can access the fields that you need.

Comment: {{ $sale->item->code }} always returns an error trying to get property of non-object. However {{ $sale->item_id }} works fine. It's just weird that I can't access the related table like usual